# FileMaker Plugin Package

Tags: plugins, filemaker, packagemaker

Is anyone familiar with installing plugins in FileMaker?

I created a package in PackageMaker using a new plugin. Everything seems to install correctly, I can see the new plugin in the extensions folder, but when I open FileMaker and look at the list of plugin it does not appear.

Anyone know what I'm missing?

I've been focusing on permissions, but even when the file is 777 it still doesn't show up.

Here are some other ideas I'm playing with:

- I have been trying to base my current package off an old one that works perfectly. But I must be missing something...
- Components. I tried adding each part as a separate 'choice' and just one 'choice' with many components, but non worked.
- Minimum Target - both 10.4
- Xcode compiling with my 10.4 sdk.

If anyone has an idea I would greatly appreciate it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is probably too complex and specific to get to many views or answers.

Here is what my solution was that worked:

I took an old Xcode Project, before my recent changes, and 'built' my old plugin. That worked in Packagemaker. So I just made a copy of that old Project and opened up my current one and moved new files over one at a time. I made some changes to the files that needed it. Then I re'built' my Project, used the new plugin in PackageMaker and it worked.

After doing this what seemed to fail was when I tried to add in another Frameworks folder. I am not really using it so I just left it out.

I don't understand enough about this stuff to know why the Framework folder would cause issues.

After reading my solution does anyone know what my issue is?

Thanks